# scale iframe video to fit the webpage

Tags: html, css, iframe

I am trying to create a web page that has a video background that plays without sound in the back, I can easily apply this to a lcoal saved video using html video tag but I when i use iframe it looks like the styles don't apply, i want to style the embed to fit the whole page, so a mobile user can see it scale to fit the whole page rather than just fitting itself to the page while maintaining aspect ratio.

```css
.banner {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="banner">
  <iframe title="vimeo-player" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay;" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: I can only think of a Javascript method to do this - is that acceptable?

Comment: sure, how would I make it work using Javascript. scale up the iframe ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Vimeo seems to display the video in the same way as `object-fit: contain` - that is, it shows the uncropped video with either full height or full width depending on how the video's aspect ratio relates to the viewport's.

The requirement is to show the video in the same way as `object-fit: cover` - that is, the whole viewport is covered by the video and either the sides are cropped or the top and bottom are depending on how the video's aspect ratio relates to the viewport's.

This can be achieved using a Javascript function to check the actual viewport dimensions versus the video's aspect ratio whenever the video is loaded or the window is resized. `transform: scale..` is then used to expand the video to cover as necessary.

In this snippet it is assumed that the video has aspect ratio 16/9. While this is currently a very common ratio, if different videos are to be used some code to get the actual aspect ratio may be needed.

Here's the code, note it won't work as an SO snippet, possibly because of nested iframes (?) but it has been tested on Edge/Chrome on Windows 10 and on various emulators and works OK. The container (=banner) has been put in an outer-container with position fixed for this demo but of course remove and use just body if that is suitable.

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
.outer-container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}  
.container {
    position: relative;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: yellow;
}
.video{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
</style>
<div class="outer-container">
<div class="container">
   <iframe class="video" src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/76979871?autoplay=1&loop=1&autopause=0&mute=1" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay"></iframe>
</div>
</div>
<script>
const vid = document.querySelector('.video');
const ratio = 16/9; //!you may need to 'ask' to find out the correct ratio, this is the one for this video and is common.
function resize() {
  const w = window.innerWidth;
  const h = window.innerHeight; 
  const scale =  ((w / h) > ratio) ? (w / (ratio * h)) : (h * ratio / w);

  vid.style.transform = 'scale(' + scale + ')';
}
vid.onload = resize;
window.onresize = resize;
</script>
```

Comment: works like a charm, also for video inside containers on the page. just saved my day after hours of brain meltdown. thanks!